# Has China ever attacked countries within the Global South for protectionism?

Tags: international-relations, china, global-south

https://www.ft.com/content/8703874e-44cb-4197-8dca-c7b555da8aef

> The Chinese government did not immediately reply to a request for
> comment. It has consistently attacked what it calls “protectionism”,
> particularly by the US and the EU.

China did not reply to a request for comment after Brazil launched anti-dumping probes against China. I was wondering if China has ever attacked countries within the Global South for protectionism.

I am wondering whether they ever did this because China calls itself a champion of the Global South and also frequently criticizes Western countries for engaging in protectionism.

If they did do that, when did this happen?

Comment: Could clarify that this case is about alleged dumping, i.e. the opposite (and complementary) situation vs protectionism. Brazil will want a ruling awarding them the right to put in a protective tariff here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Global South" may be a somewhat unclear term, but it is often taken to refer to countries that are relatively poor in terms of GDP per capita or that have been subject to colonialism in recent history, even if, for instance, they are entirely within the Northern Hemisphere. By this standard, India would qualify, and China [has frequently criticized India's restrictions on Chinese applications, including at the World Trade Organization](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.economictimes.com/news/economy/foreign-trade/at-wto-china-accuses-india-of-discriminatory-trade-measures/amp_articleshow/78480865.cms).

To the extent that China has not criticized many countries outside of Europe and the USA for alleged protectionism, this may be because the volume of trade is simply much lower—the USA and the EU as a whole are China's largest trade partners by far—or because many smaller countries have fewer restrictions on Chinese products (and vice versa).

Comment: Interestingly, India and China seem to have never initiated an actual WTO complaint against each other

Comment: For the time being. Certainly [there is often little love lost between them there.](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business/india-business/india-blames-us-for-holding-up-dispute-settlement-at-wto-blocks-chinas-attempt-for-investment-pact/articleshow/108082791.cms)

Answer (score 4):

By "attacked", I assume the question means, made a serious accusation. One way to look for such disputes is via the WTO, which PRC joined with much fanfare in 2001.

China has filed 25 WTO cases as complainant. Thus far, none were against the Global South.

- 17 against US
- 5 against EU or former EC
- 1 against Australia
- 1 against Italy
- 1 against Greece

[[source: WTO]](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/dispu_e/dispu_by_country_e.htm)